# Creating a user profile with SoftLayer_User_Customer REST API

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

I am trying to create a new user profile and the JSON fields passed in are ignored.

The following is the URL with method POST

```
https://api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_User_Customer.json
```

The JSON payload is:

```
{
"parameters" : [
    {
      "address1" : "1101 Kitchawan Road",
      "city" : "Yorktown Heights",
      "companyName" : "IBM - www Account",
      "state" : "NY",
      "country" : "US",
      "postalCode" : "10598",
      "firstName" : "hello",
      "lastName" : "thisguy",
      "email" : "thisguy@nn.ibm.com",
      "permissionSystemVersion" : "1",
      "timezoneId" : "117",
      "username" : "286900_thisguy@nn.ibm.com",
      "secondaryPasswordTimeoutDays" : 90,
      "managedByOpenIdConnectFlag" : false,
      "userStatusId" : 1001,
      "sslVpnAllowedFlag" : true
   },
  "xxxxxxxx!",
  "xxxxxxxx!"
 ]
}
```

The JSON returned from the create is:

```
      'userStatusId' => 1001,
      'timezoneId' => 117,
      'accountId' => 286900,
      'statusDate' => undef,
      'userLinks' => [],
      'locale' => {
                    'friendlyName' => 'English',
                    'name' => 'English',
                    'id' => 1,
                    'languageTag' => 'en-US'
                  },
      'state' => 'NY',
      'secondaryLoginRequiredFlag' => undef,
      'msn' => '',
      'managedByOpenIdConnectFlag' => bless( do{\(my $o = 1)}, 'JSON::PP::Boolean' ),
      'email' => 'thisguy@nn.ibm.com',
      'permissionSystemVersion' => 2,
      'vpnManualConfig' => bless( do{\(my $o = 0)}, 'JSON::PP::Boolean' ),
      'id' => 6713227,
      'secondaryPasswordTimeoutDays' => 0,
      'yahoo' => '',
      'denyAllResourceAccessOnCreateFlag' => $VAR1->{'vpnManualConfig'},
      'secondaryLoginManagementFlag' => undef,
      'localeId' => 1,
      'firstName' => hello',
      'timezone' => {
                      'longName' => '(GMT-05:00) America/New York - EST',
                      'name' => 'America/New_York',
                      'id' => 117,
                      'shortName' => 'EST',
                      'offset' => '-0500'
                    },
      'sslVpnAllowedFlag' => $VAR1->{'vpnManualConfig'},
      'companyName' => 'IBM - www Account',
      'isMasterUserFlag' => $VAR1->{'vpnManualConfig'},
      'username' => '286900_thisguy@nn.ibm.com',
      'pptpVpnAllowedFlag' => $VAR1->{'vpnManualConfig'},
      'userStatus' => {
                        'name' => 'Active',
                        'id' => 1001,
                        'keyName' => 'ACTIVE'
                      },
      'passwordExpireDate' => undef,
      'address1' => '1101 Kitchawan Road',
      'sms' => '',
      'daylightSavingsTimeFlag' => $VAR1->{'vpnManualConfig'},
      'officePhone' => '',
      'city' => 'Yorktown Heights',
      'icq' => '',
      'createDate' => '2017-06-06T08:46:54-04:00',
      'savedId' => '6713227',
      'lastName' => 'thisguy',
      'displayName' => 'CarlosF',
      'secondaryPasswordModifyDate' => '2017-06-06T08:46:55-04:00',
      'country' => 'US',
      'modifyDate' => '2017-06-06T08:46:55-04:00',
      'alternatePhone' => '',
      'forumPasswordHash' => '._staIj7diist1',
      'aim' => '',
      'managedByFederationFlag' => $VAR1->{'vpnManualConfig'},
      'address2' => '',
      'parentId' => 151785,
      'postalCode' => '10598'
    };
```

This all looks good, except for the fiedl 'displayName'

I now issue the URL with a GET request:

```
https://api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Account/getUsers/6713227.json?objectMask=mask[virtualGuestCount,virtualGuests.id,virtualGuests.hostname,virtualGuests.status,hardwareCount,hardware.id,hardware.hostname,hardware.hardwareStatus,userStatus,apiAuthenticationKeyCount,apiAuthenticationKeys,loginAttemptCount,successfulLoginCount,unsuccessfulLoginCount]
```

The JSON payload returned is:

```
'userStatusId' => 1001,
'timezoneId' => 113,
'accountId' => 286900,
'permissions' => [
]
'state' => 'NY',
'secondaryLoginRequiredFlag' => undef,
'managedByOpenIdConnectFlag' => bless( do{\(my $o = 1)}, 'JSON::PP::Boolean' ),
'email' => 'thisguy@nn.ibm.com',
'actionCount' => 25,
'permissionSystemVersion' => 2,
'vpnManualConfig' => bless( do{\(my $o = 0)}, 'JSON::PP::Boolean' ),
'id' => 6713227,
'secondaryPasswordTimeoutDays' => 0,
'denyAllResourceAccessOnCreateFlag' => $VAR1->{'vpnManualConfig'},
'secondaryLoginManagementFlag' => undef,
'firstName' => 'hello',
'localeId' => 1,
'parent' => { 
]
'timezone' => {
     'longName' => '(GMT-06:00) America/Chicago - CST',
     'name' => 'America/Chicago',
     'id' => 113,
     'shortName' => 'CST',
     'offset' => '-0600'
    },
'sslVpnAllowedFlag' => $VAR1->{'vpnManualConfig'},
'companyName' => 'IBM - www Account',
'isMasterUserFlag' => $VAR1->{'vpnManualConfig'},
'username' => '286900_thisguy@us.ibm.com',
'pptpVpnAllowedFlag' => $VAR1->{'vpnManualConfig'},
'userStatus' => {
                        'name' => 'Active',
                        'id' => 1001,
                        'keyName' => 'ACTIVE'
                      },
 'apiAuthenticationKeys' => [
 ]
 'passwordExpireDate' => undef,
 'loginAttemptCount' => 0,
 'address1' => '2455 South Rd',
 'openIdConnectUserName' => 'thisguy@nn.ibm.com',
 'actions' => [
 ]
 'daylightSavingsTimeFlag' => $VAR1->{'vpnManualConfig'},
      'unsuccessfulLoginCount' => 0,
      'successfulLoginCount' => 0,
      'city' => 'Poughkeepsie',
      'createDate' => '2017-06-06T08:46:54-04:00',
      'savedId' => '6713227',
      'lastName' => 'thisguy',
      'displayName' => 'hellog',
      'country' => 'US',
      'secondaryPasswordModifyDate' => '2017-06-06T08:46:55-04:00',
      'modifyDate' => '2017-06-06T08:46:55-04:00',
      'apiAuthenticationKeyCount' => 1,
      'forumPasswordHash' => '._staIj7diist1',
      'managedByFederationFlag' => $VAR1->{'vpnManualConfig'},
      'parentId' => 151785,
      'postalCode' => '12601-5400'

    }
```

Notice that th4e address is not the same as returned from the create and the timezone is wrong. The create ignored certain fields passed in on the create.

Answer (score 0):

This is an issue for accounts with bluemix and it is already reported. Some values like address and time zone are saved with data of master account.

You can try to update/change those values by editing the user with the method [SoftLayer_User_Customer::editObject](http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_User_Customer/editObject).

Also you can submit a ticket in order to get further assistance with this bug.

**About displayName**

If you don't set this value in the JSON request, it is automatically set with the firstName and first character of lastName.

Comment: The timezone of the master account is 117, but somehow the timeOne of 113 is set. Very strange, What is the status of the reported issue in Bluemix? Was it reported in SoftLayr or a bluemix tag in stackoverflow?

Comment: It was reported in Softlayer and the status is "In Progress". I recommend you submit a ticket in order to get more information about this issue.