# GO lang library to add user profile

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

I am using the GO Lang SoftLayer package to add a user profile with the following template.

```
    email := w3id
username := "286000_" + w3id
address1 := "1101 Kitchawan Road"
city := "Yorktown Heights"
companyName := "WIS - RIS Account"
state := "NY"
country := "US"
postalCode := "10598"
timezoneID := 117
userStatusID := 1001
sslVpnAllowedFlag := true
templateObject := datatypes.User_Customer{
    Email:             &email,
    Username:          &username,
    Address1:          &address1,
    City:              &city,
    CompanyName:       &companyName,
    State:             &state,
    Country:           &country,
    PostalCode:        &postalCode,
    FirstName:         &firstname,
    LastName:          &lastname,
    TimezoneId:        &timezoneID,
    UserStatusId:      &userStatusID,
    SslVpnAllowedFlag: &sslVpnAllowedFlag,
}

fmt.Printf("Registering w3id %s, %s %s, with SL\n", w3id, firstname, lastname)

//password := pg.NewPassword(12)
password := "Temp4now!"
userService := services.GetUserCustomerService(sess)
u, err := userService.CreateObject(&templateObject, &password, &password)
if err != nil {
    fmt.Println(err)
    return
}
fmt.Printf("User registered: %s, password: %s\n", *u.Username, password)
```

After the user profile is added, the city, address1, timezone id, postal code aren't what was specified in te template.

City is "Poughkeepsie"
Address1 is "2455 South Road"
Postal code is "12601-5400"
timezone id is 113 not 117 as specified.  This timezone isn't specified on this account anywhere.

Why are the template values not used?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Creating a user profile with SoftLayer\_User\_Customer REST API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44392928/creating-a-user-profile-with-softlayer-user-customer-rest-api)

Answer (score 0):

This issue was reported in SoftLayer, data of created users are changed with master user profile information, it happens for accounts with bluemix. [Creating a user profile with SoftLayer_User_Customer REST API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44392928/creating-a-user-profile-with-softlayer-user-customer-rest-api).

To solve this you can update/change the user values by using the  [SoftLayer_User_Customer::editObject](http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_User_Customer/editObject) method.

If you are planning to create more users, I recommend you submit a ticket to get further assistance, but take account that this is not an API issue.